# Min and max auto Id column plus other columns from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve data from a table relative to 3 columns i.e. max and min Id for every unique `reservation_Id` and `rnoid` pair.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    R1.*,
    R2.Id, R2.Res_Id, R2.rNoid
FROM 
    dbo.Res_Id R1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Res_Id R2 ON R2.rNoid = R1.rNoid
                  AND (R2.Id > R1.Id  --min
                       OR (R2.Id = R1.Id 
                           AND r2.Res_Id <> r1.Res_Id)
                      ) 
                  -- AND R2.rNoid <> R1.rNoid
WHERE 
    R2.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    R1.Id
```

Results:

```
id  Res_Id, rNoid, xxx_x, yyy_x, user_id
-------------------------------------------
 1    1      33       5      null     1
 2    3      44       0      3        1
 3    13     22       0      null     1
 4    1      22       2      5        2
 5    3       5       0      5        2
 6    3      77       1      3        2
```

I am getting some unique pairs skipped.

Comment: The result set columns don't match the query's selected columns.

Comment: i did remove other unnecessary columns on what i posted coz they r not relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. This will create `min(id)` under `cte` section and `max(id)` under `ct` section. After that you may easily get the `inner join` on `Res_Id` and 
`rNoid` to get your records.

```
  ; with cte as (
       SELECT r.Res_Id, r.rNoid, MIN(r.id) as MinId
       FROM dbo.Res_Id R1
       GROUP BY r.Res_Id, r.rNoid
    ),
    ct as (
       SELECT r.Res_Id, r.rNoid, MAX(r.id) as MaxId
       FROM dbo.Res_Id R1
       GROUP BY r.Res_Id, r.rNoid    
    )
    SELECT C.Res_Id, C.rNoid, MinId, MaxId FROM CTE AS C INNER JOIN CT AS CT 
    ON C.Res_Id = CT.Res_Id AND C.rNoid = CT.rNoid
```

Comment: Man u R a savior. Tx. Tested and confirmed Working. Thank you too for the Precise explanation on how to use that code.

Comment: how can i filter to be left with just one record for any duplicates

Comment: post a new question, with your expected output, tag me we'll work on that

Answer (score 0):

> max and min Id for every unique reservation_Id and rnoid pair.

You seem to want a simple aggregation query:

```
SELECT r.Res_Id, r.rNoid, MIN(r.id), MAX(r.id)
FROM dbo.Res_Id R1
GROUP BY r.Res_Id, r.rNoid;
```

Comment: no i need to be able to get the latest id for every Res_Id and rNoid unique pair

Comment: @Gomesh . . . This answer returns both the maximum and minimum id, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: sorry i may have loosely presented my request but DarkRob's reply perfectly fitted my request. tx also for your reply it would also have worked.